# Can't figure out why this prints out 63

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

came across this code and tried to solve it ... but do not quite understand why it prints out 63?

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for(int z= 0; z < 5; z++)
    {
        if ((++x > 2)&&(++y > 2))
        {
            x++;  
        }
    }
    System.out.println(x+""+y);
}
```

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. Thats what they are for.

Comment: google postfix and prefix increment operators ...

Comment: Also, "short-circuit evaluation" comes into play here.

Comment: It should print 42 !

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, ++x means x is being added 1, and afterwards read for the check in the if statement. So x is 1 the first time you check it.

But there is another thing in Java, if you check two statements, like you do in the following:

```
if ((++x > 2)&&(++y > 2))
```

If the first check fails, the second doesn not get executed.

I written the output in console, having ----- for all for loop cycles:

```
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0
if: (false && (not executed) )
x: 1
-----
x: 1
y: 0
z: 1
if: (false && (not executed) )
x: 2
-----
x: 2
y: 0
z: 2
if: (true && false)
x: 3
y: 1
-----
x: 3
y: 1
z: 3
if: (true && false)
x: 4
y: 2
-----
x: 4
y: 2
z: 4
if: (true && true)
x: 5
y: 3
x: 6
-----
63
```